# Functions of One Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

(a) Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with pdf $f(x)=\frac{2}{9}(x+1), -1<x<2$.

Determine the pdf of $Y=X^2$

(b) Repeat part (a) but where $X$ has the pdf $f(x)=\frac{2}{9}(x+2),-2<x<1$

**My attempt**

(a)
Because $Y=X^2$, and because $x \in (-1,2)$, we have $X=\pm \sqrt Y$.

Let $v_1(Y)=-\sqrt Y$ and $v_2(Y)=\sqrt Y$.

Now $X=-\sqrt Y$ when $x \in (-1,0)$ and $X=\sqrt Y$ when $x \in (0,2)$

So when $0<y<1$ we have $x \in (-1,0) \cup (0,1)$. Thus, $G(y)=P(Y<y)=P(X^2<y)=P(-\sqrt y<X< \sqrt y)=\int_{v_1(y)}^{v_2(y)} f(x) dx=\int_{-1}^{v_1(y)}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{v_2(y)}f(x)dx$ $\Rightarrow g(y)=G'(y)=\frac{2}{9\sqrt y}$.

And when $1<y<4$ we have $x \in (1,2)$. Thus, $G(y)=P(Y<y)=P(X^2<y)=P(X<\sqrt y)=\int_{1}^{v_2(y)}f(x)dx \Rightarrow g(y)=G'(y)=\frac{1+\sqrt y}{9 \sqrt y}$

$\therefore g(y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{2}{9 \sqrt y}, &  \hspace{2mm} y \in (0,1) \\
        \frac{1+\sqrt y}{9 \sqrt y}, & \hspace{2mm} y \in (1,4)\\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

(b) As $Y=X^2$ whereby $-2<x<1$, then $X=\pm \sqrt Y$.

$X=-\sqrt Y$ when $x \in (-2,0)$ and $X=\sqrt Y$ when $x \in (0,1)$.

Let $v_1(Y)=-\sqrt Y$ and $v_2(Y)=\sqrt Y$.

When $0<y<1$ we have $x \in (-1,0) \cup (0,1)$, so that $G(y)=P(Y<y)=P(X^2<y)=P(-\sqrt y<X< \sqrt y)=\int_{-1}^{v_1(y)} f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{v_2(y)} f(x)dx$ $\Rightarrow g(y)=G'(y)=\frac{4}{9 \sqrt y}$

I'm having trouble figuring out the the correct limits of integration when $1<y<4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(b)$, if you are first finding CDF and then taking its derivative,

$F_Y(y) = P (Y \lt y) = P( - \sqrt y \lt X \lt \sqrt y) $

$i$) If $ ~- \sqrt y \gt -1$ and $\sqrt y \lt 1~$, then

$ \displaystyle F_Y(y) = \int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y} \frac 2 9 (x+2) ~ dx = \frac {8\sqrt y}{9}$

So, $ \displaystyle f_Y(y) = \frac{4}{9\sqrt y}, 0 \lt y \lt 1$

$ii$) If $ ~- \sqrt y \lt - 1$,

$ \displaystyle F_Y(y) = \int_{-\sqrt y}^{-1} \frac 29 (x+2) ~ dx = \frac{4 \sqrt y - y - 3}{9}$

Or, $ \displaystyle f_Y(y) = \frac{2 - \sqrt y}{9\sqrt y}, ~1 \lt y \lt 4$

Answer (score 0):

> b) I'm having trouble figuring out the the correct limits of integration when 1<y<4.

In this interval the transformation is monotone thus $f_Y(y)$ can be easy found using the standard formula

$$f_Y(y)=f_X[g^{-1}(y)]\left| \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)  \right|$$

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{2-\sqrt{y}}{9\sqrt{y}}$$

Comment: In this interval the transformation is monotone, because $y_1<y_2 \Rightarrow  \sqrt y_1<\sqrt y_2$? Could you explain how to derive the inverse $g^{-1}(y)$ in this context? I'm not familiar with this formula. Also, how would you arrive at this answer using the approach that I used?

Comment: @Karam : If you do a drawing of the problem you realize that

$$\mathbb{P}[Y\le y]=\mathbb{P}[X>-\sqrt{y}]$$

derivate RHS expression and find the same density I showed using a different way

Comment: Is that because when $1<y<4$, we have $x \in (-2,1)$, and thus $G(y)=P(-\sqrt y<X<1)$? So when we take its derivative with respect to $y$, then $g(y)=\frac{-(2-\sqrt y)}{9 \sqrt y}$. But since density function is always positive, $g(y)=\frac{2-\sqrt y}{9 \sqrt y}$?